# How to use $stateprovider without # in URL?

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

How to use `$stateprovider` without `#` in URL?

If we use `$locationprovider.html5mode(true)` then first time it was loading correctly but after refreshing the page the state is not loading and error is displaying.

I will explain you the scenario. We are using ASP.NET web api as back end server and front end is purely HTML application with angular.JS . we are not facing any issues with backend server. we don't have issues with api calls. I will explain with a example: www.test.com/#/main/home is redirecting to www.test.com/main/home using $state.go and rendering the view perfectly. But after redirecting to www.test.com/main/home if we refresh the page we are getting 404 error. Please help out

I am looking for to provide URL as per use choice. So I need to eliminate the `#` for that.

Comment: `$stateProvider` works perfectly fine without the `#`.  The problem is with the way your server is handling html5mode.  Since you haven't mentioned which server technology you are using, a complete answer isn't possible, but you should review the many other questions related to html5mode posted here for your particular server, and the official documentation for UI-Router html5mode https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode.

Comment: @Claies I will explain you the scenario. We are using ASP.NET web api as back end server and front end is purely HTML application with angular.JS . we are not facing any issues with backend server. we don't have issues with api calls. I will explain with a example: www.test.com/#/main/home is redirecting to www.test.com/main/home using $state.go and rendering the view perfectly. But after redirecting to www.test.com/main/home if we refresh the page we are getting 404 error. Please help out

Comment: This is **exactly** an issue with the server.  when you request `http://www.test.com/main/home` from the *server*, there is no route configured there, which causes a 404.  Read the link I posted, specifically the portion about enabling redirects in ASP.Net C#.

Comment: perhaps for more context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258515/angularjs-how-does-location-html5mode-work

Answer (score 0):

The problem with html5mode(true) and page reload is that in HTML 5 mode the browser sends the full URL to the server when a page reload is triggered. And if the resource of the full URL does not exist on the server, an error is returned.
So to fix your problem, you need to add a rule on the server to always send the same .html file no matter what URL is called.
The $stateprovider will then initialize the client side state accordingly.

Comment: I will explain you the scenario. We are using ASP.NET web api as back end server and front end is purely HTML application with angular.JS . we are not facing any issues with backend server. we don't have issues with api calls. I will explain with a example: www.test.com/#/main/home is redirecting to www.test.com/main/home using $state.go and rendering the view perfectly. But after redirecting to www.test.com/main/home if we refresh the page we are getting 404 error. Please help out

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-write the url with .htaccess

Check this link out:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode