# AAD with JWT: Hide Id_Token from URL

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, azure, token, adal

I'm using AAD to request a token. I have a redirect in Azure to https://localhost:44313/index.html, however, when the login is made and it redirects, token is write on my URL, something like this:
https://localhost:44313/index.html#!#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhb...

I'm using ADAL, and if I print {{userInfo}} it prints nothing, but, if I remove #! from url, it has a correct action, my url turns to: https://localhost:44313/index.html and print {{userInfo}} as it should be.

Why this is happening, what should I do to avoid token on url? Should I have some action to remove manually #! from url?

This is a Native-Application on Azure, using Angular and HTML.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When Html5Mode is enabled, the links on the page are replaced by
>   Angular with event listeners. When these events are triggered, the
>   current page is pushed into the browser history, and the new page is
>   loaded. This gives the illusion that you are navigating to a new page,
>   and even allows for the back button to operate.

see [AngularJS - How does $location html5Mode work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258515/angularjs-how-does-location-html5mode-work)
Use following to remove !#

```
angular.module('app', [])

    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {



        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: true });
    });
```

On the redirect page that you have selected on Azure, in this case, https://localhost:44313/index.html, edit HTML and add the following:

```
<head> <base href="/"> </head>
```

Thank you

Comment: While enabling HTML5 mode can be the solution, please add some details why this works. And also what it means for the server (as it will now have to ignore any routes it gets that are meant to be processed client-side).

Comment: It's doesn't work. Should I insert a <base> on my index.html where AAD redirects?

Comment: <head>
  <base href="/">
</head>

Comment: Thank you in advance for the help, now it replace the second hash for the html code %23
:
https://localhost:44313/index.html#!%23id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJ

but still maintain the token in url

Comment: It's done :)

I replace the tag for:

$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: true });


Thank you very much